# PHP error when connecting to database

Tags: php, database

I keep getting the below error when i try to run my php file in localhost. Can anyone tell me what the problem is? My code is below. Thanks

```
<?PHP
    require "conn.php";
    $password = "John123";
    $email = "John@lally.com";
    $mysql_qry = "select * from hospital where password like '$password' and email like '$email';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn ,$mysql_qry);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "Login success";
    }
    else{
        echo "Login not successful";
    }
?>
```

[image: SQL error]

This is the code for conn.php:

```
<?php
    $db_name = "hospital";
    $mysql_username = "root";
    $mysql_password = "";
    $server_name = "localhost";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $db_name);
    if($conn){
         echo "Connection success";
    }
    else{
         echo "Connection not successful";
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Is the tab in the query intentional?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? It's probably not intentional

Comment: email like '$email';"; please check this line

Comment: Oh sorry between 'and' and 'email'? That's just a typo in my question, it's not in my coe

Comment: I removed the tab but it's not the issue

Comment: For reference on the picture, line 21 = the if statement

Comment: $mysql_qry = "select * from hospital where password like ' ".$password." ' and email like ' ".$email." ' " ;

Comment: can you show the code of conn.php

Comment: Adding to the original question now

Comment: You are getting this error message because your query fails and therefore returns 'false' (a boolean value) instead of the result from the query. What happens if you leave the password out of the query and just query for the e-mail?

Comment: I tried and no change occurs

Comment: How does the table hospital look?

Comment: It's got five fields: id, doctor_name, doctor_number, password and email

Comment: Did you try changing the ' to " ? ('$password' => "$password")?

Comment: I did that and got the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$password' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp64\www\Login.php on line 19... Line 19 is $mysql_qry

Comment: What do you get for `die(var_dump($mysql_qry));`? If you add that below your query and run the code.

Comment: Nothing changes, still the same error. Could you look at mysql_qry to the end of the if statment and see if you can see nay problems? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the table is called hospital and not just the database? Your database is called hospital as well...

Comment: Ahh that was what the issue was. The table should have been named 'doctors'. Thank you for the help! It's fixed now

Comment: Happy that I could help!

Comment: I answered below with the fixed code